# When I'm using CSS hyphens after remove all style with 'all: unset;', CSS hyphens doesn't affect in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I'm removing all the styles with this CSS code:

```
* {
    all: unset;
    display: revert;
}
```

CSS Hyphens don't affect in Chrome browser. For example:

```
div {
  font-size: 3rem;
  
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
  width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/JjpPePJ/09ae1f8006ae576a0b126bf4dca8449a)

Any way to solve it without deleting the CSS reset code above?

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug in Chrome, but I've been able to identify so far that adding `all: unset;` to `html` tag specifically is what causes the issue. If you change `* { ... }` to `html * { ... }` or remove `all: unset;`, it works.

Comment: @Sumit Add it as an answer because it helps me to solve the issue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not deeply familiar with the [`hyphens`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) CSS property, but it seems that it only works when you've specified the language in the DOM using `lang=`. E.g. `<html lang="en">...</html>` will allow you to use `hyphens` anywhere across the document.

In your [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/JjpPePJ/09ae1f8006ae576a0b126bf4dca8449a), the `lang="en"` property is automatically added by CodePen to the `<html>` attribute.

Now what Chrome seems to do (and Firefox *doesn't* do) is that it sees the `all: unset;` property on the HTML attribute and just forgets that `lang="en"` exists, at least for the purpose of hyphens.

You can confirm this by adding `lang` attribute to the div directly, and adding `all: unset;` only on that div, then removing it from the div.

A quick fix here could be to change your CSS reset selector to `html *` instead of `*`, i.e. keeping everything inside `<html>` tag but excluding the `<html>` tag itself, if you're okay with this compromise:

```
html * {
    all: unset;
    display: revert;
}
```

[Complete example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/smtchahal/pen/BaYBvRL)

Answer (score 1):

There's another way of fixing this by setting the locale for the HTML root:

```
:root {
  -webkit-locale: 'en';
}
```

For some reason, `revert` and `initial` don't seem to work.

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- More on -webkit-locale at stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083